# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repository.BookRepositoryTest' in Junit Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am writing a junit test for spring data repository. But i can't autowire repository interface. Program is running if i run main method and spring can detect all repositories,services,entities but if i run a test it gives this error :

> UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name
> 'repository.BookRepositoryTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed
> through field 'bookRepository'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'app.repository.BookRepository' available:
> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
> Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={BookRepository.class})
public class BookRepositoryTest
{
    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;
    @Test
    public void save()
    {
        Book book=new Book();
        bookRepository.save(book);
    }
}
```

```java
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book,Integer>
{
    Book findByName(String name);
}
```

Project Structure:

```
src
    main
        java
            app
                entity
                    Book.java
                repository
                    BookRepository.java
                service
                    BookService.java
                App.java
        resources
            application.properties
        webapp
    test
        java
            repository
                BookRepositoryTest.java
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repository.BookRepositoryTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'app.repository.BookRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:391)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'app.repository.BookRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1655)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the implementation of the `BookRepository` interface in the context. Where in your project do you have the class that `implements BookRepository` and where is the current class? EDIT: Or is it supposed to be mocked?

Comment: Remove the `classes` from `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: M.Denium if i remove that gives me error.

Comment: Kudin in spring data there is no class that implements repository interfaces.

Comment: It looks like a package scan issue. What is the structure of your project? Does your application start-up with `BookRepository` autowired in context?

Comment: Are there any class that is implementing this interface?

Comment: NKR it is JpaRepository. There is no class that implement that class. Spring autowiring that interface.

Comment: So... you're trying to test the spring data implementation of your interface??? Why exactly?

Comment: Jason Warner actually i am new to testing. Should not i test repositories ?

Comment: mate00 program is running on normal start. Spring can find all repositories,entities,services. Structure is repository is under the app.repository package. Class that has main method and SpringBootApplication annotation is under the app package.

Comment: I would just write `@SpringBootTest` without `classes` parameter. Do you get error in this case? What is it?

Comment: @mate00 if i don't write classes parameter gives this error: Unable to find a SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use ContextConfiguration or SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

Comment: I am preety sure you've messed up a bit the packages structure of your project. Can you draw it or post a screenshot?

Comment: @mate00 i added project structure.

Comment: I think my answer should help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is, that your main and test packages differ:

`BookRepository` is in `app.entity.repository` and your test is in `repository`. Try by aligning it and move your test to `src/test/java/app/entity/repository`.

Comment: BookRepository is under app.repository not app.entity.repository. I moved test to src/test/java/app/repository and it worked. Thank you i have been trying to solve this for several days.

Comment: I'm so glad I could help. Please consider a vote-up of my answer. :)

Comment: If i try to run save method it gives same error again.

Comment: Hmm, that's quite strange if it worked once and suddenly stopped. What have you changed between moving to different packages, running a test (that was working) and running again?

Comment: I handled that. Your answer is correct. Thank you again.

Comment: I removed classes parameter from SpringBootTest and it worked.

Comment: Can you provide an example if the BookRepository being in a different root package ( like not in app.entity.repository)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the  BookRepository in following way

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BookRepository .class})
public class BookRepositoryTest{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced a similar problem. I have injected the dependent class using @MockBean annotation.

> ```
> @MockBean
> private S3StorageService s3StorageService;
> ```

The above solution worked for me.